# Finding general information about the Dzyaloshinskii-Moriya interaction (DMI)

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, ferromagnetism, exchange-interaction

I have to do an assignment on the [Dzyaloshinskii-Moriya interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_exchange) for a magnetism (in condensed matter) course that I am following. My teacher said that this topic is rather popular, but I cannot seem to find a section in a book or even a review article about it. If anyone knows of a book with a decent section about this, I would love to hear it. I am mainly trying to understand how this interaction follows from the spin-orbit interaction, but I honestly have a fairly general lack of information.

[What I have tried so far is the following. My teacher recommended some books for the course like Blundell's, Stöhr's and Coey's books on magnetism, but none of them go into more detail than showing the Hamiltonian. I have obviously looked at the original articles by Dzyaloshinskii and Moriya, but these are rather old and a bit hard to understand. I also looked at some recent master theses I found on google on the subject, but they did not contain very much information.]

Comment: I'm not sure there is much general information about it. It is a (at least typically) subleading term in the Hamiltonian, so its impact on the physics will vary between systems. Thus I think it's easier to look separately on literature about its impact on topics you may be interested in, e.g. weak ferromagnetism, spiral orders, skyrmions, geometrically frustrated systems, interfacial DMI, topological magnons, etc.  By the way, I think Moriya's original paper is significantly easier to read than Dzyaloshinskii's.

Comment: I think [Moriya's paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.120.91) may be sufficient to see how the interaction follows from the spin-orbit interaction, but another approach could be to look how it emerges in some specific system. One (admittedly complicated) example is the pyrochlore lattice considered in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1606), and especially the supplemental material. If it's just for an assignment, it might not be worth working out the full geometry, but hopefully it shows enough of the structure of the calculation.